# Angular routing load wrong component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have this routing file:

```
{
    path: '',pathMatch:'full', loadChildren: () => import('./component/login/login.module').then(m =>
      m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'section2', loadChildren: () => import('./componenti/section2/section2.module').then(m =>
      m.Section2)
  },
```

When I go on `http://localhost:4200/`

I see the login component and it works fine, but when I put the correct parameters I do:

```
this.router.navigate(['/section2']);
```

But when I do on /section do it shows me the login component
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you show the routing you have declared in the section2 module - that's what's going to determine how your route is matched.

Comment: u have syntax error componenti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can debug it better if you can provide a stackblitz

Looking at above code i can see there is a spelling mistake

./componenti

instead of

/component for section2